# MongoDB nodejs create new instance from function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to follow [a tutorial](http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb), but after the creation of a new file for the mongodb connection I have this code in the `mongoConnection` file :

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Connection = require('mongodb').Connection;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var BSON = require('mongodb').BSON;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

ArticleProvider = function(host, port) {
  this.db= new Db('node-mongo-blog', new Server(host, port, {auto_reconnect: true}, {}));
  this.db.open(function(){});
};
```

In another file I'm trying to use this code to define a new `ArticleProvider` to set `host` and `port`:

```
var express = require('express');
var ArticleProvider = require('./mongoConnection').ArticleProvider;
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('../')(server);
var connect = require('connect');
app.use(connect.logger('dev'));
app.use(connect.json());  
app.use(connect.urlencoded());

var articleProvider = new ArticleProvider('localhost', 27017);
```

After I start the app with nodejs I get this error:

```
var articleProvider = new ArticleProvider('localhost', 27017);
                      ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: apparently you are not using [module.exports](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports)

Comment: @NeilLunn hi Neil please review topic i'm insert tutorial link into post reference: http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb

Comment: Why would I care about what someone else writes that is likely incorrect? Read the documentation in the link provided. You are doing it wrong.

Comment: Your mongoConnection file should have the `exports.ArticleProvider = ArticleProvider;` declaration at the end.

Comment: @NeilLunn in fact right with you, i get this warning now: http://paste.debian.net/161071/

Comment: @chridam Actually it should be `exports.ArticleProvider = function(...)` but I don't hold much hope for understanding here.

Comment: @NeilLunn Likewise, obviously the basic module.exports concepts are not being grasped here.